# Why does setting CharField max_length to 255 solve DataError (Django)?

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.5

This is a solved problem, but it's quite unclear for me how it works. I use **Django** with **PostgreSQL**. I have a model with several fields. One of them, called `track_code`, is a `CharField(max_length=13)`. There is a method in this class which contains the following block:

```
    new_order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(shop=fshop, order_id=order['number'])
    new_order.shop = fshop
    new_order.order_id = order['number']
    new_order.status = order['fulfillment-status']
    new_order.created_at = order['created-at']
    new_order.api_id = order['id']
    new_order.payment = order['financial-status']
    new_order.track_code = track
    new_order.save()
```

Here `shop` is a `ForeignKey`. Every time I run this method, I get `django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(13)`. That appears to be a problem with the `track_code` field. `track` length never exceeds 12, that's **for sure**. *I found a solution on SO for SlugField, not for CharField, but it works for both. **It requires setting field's max_length to 255***.

The only thing I don't understand is **why does it work?** I've never tried to set `track_code` to something longer than 12, and that means I am not supposed to get these errors. But I do, and that's strange.

Comment: And the problematic value of `track` is? If you don't know, [query logging might help](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django-db-backends).

Comment: It depends, but typical values are 'LOK3212779' and '1043830344', both strings